# Python multiprocessing.Process not starting

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pyscripter

I'm using PyScripter for Python 2.7.5 on Windows.

This code should clearly work. Why doesn't it print `running... let's kill it...`?

```
import multiprocessing
import time

# bar
def bar():
    for i in range(100):
        print "Tick"
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start bar as a process
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar)
    p.start()

    # Wait for 10 seconds or until process finishes
    p.join(5)

    # If thread is still active
    if p.is_alive():
        print "running... let's kill it..."

        # Terminate
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
```

Output in Pyscripter before saying py file:

```
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>> 
>>>
```

Output in Pyscripter after saving py file:

```
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized  ***
>>> 
running... let's kill it...
>>>
```

Output in cmd.exe:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>python test.py
Tick
Tick
Tick
Tick
Tick
running... let's kill it...
```

Comment: pyscripter is just an IDE afaik so it shouldnt make any difference ... does it work correctly if you run it in the normal python terminal?

Comment: Just tested it in command line, and it works as expected. Updated the question with more information.

Comment: It's probably just a limitation of the interpreter built into pyscripter . IDLE doesn't handle multiprocessing properly, either.